# Magento 1.9 - Resize images

Tags: magento-1.9, module, admin, varien-file-uploader, image-resizing

I create a custom module in Magento 1.9 to upload some images. But I want to have this big images as a thumbnails too, how I can made a resize of the big images?

```
    if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != null) {
        $result['file'] = '';
        try {   
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS.'images/'.DS ;
            $result = $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['image']['name'] );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage() . '  '. $path);
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
        $data['image'] = 'images/'.$result['file'];
    }
```

**How I can duplicate and resize uploaded images to create thumbnails automatically.**

Thank you

Comment: do you want to resize image after saving images ?

Comment: Hi, the images are already save, I just want to have a new variable for example small_images and this variable to be resized. The idea is to have thumbnails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link http://vagento.com/magento-resize-image-function/
I hope it'll help you with what you want.

Comment: but how I can duplicate the uploaded image?

Comment: @Robert Read the instruction on the provided link.

Comment: I already read that but there you don't duplicate nothing, there you just get the base image and then you resize the base image, I need to create the thumbnails automatically

Comment: will be fine if you can reproduce that code here with my requirements, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For resize the image please use the below code. I hope it will work

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != null) {
    $result['file'] = '';
    try {
        // changing image url into direct path
        $dirImg = Mage::getBaseDir().str_replace("/",DS,strstr($_FILES['image']['name'],'/media'));

        // resized image path (media/IMAGE_NAME)
        $imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS."resized".DS.$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $imageObj = new Varien_Image($dirImg);
        $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
        $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
        $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
        $imageObj->resize(120, 120);
        $result = $imageObj->save($imageResized);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage() . '  '. $path);
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
        return;
    }
    $data['image'] = 'images/'.$result['file'];
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, and how I will made the difference between big images and the thumbnails? So there I upload the big / main images in the backend, and I need to create thumbnails for the main images, so the main images will remain the same, I need to resize thumbnails, not main Image

Comment: You can save your main image in another path directory before the resize image.

Comment: perfect but how I can do this?